# Class that define Base 3 number in .net Framework ( .net 4.0 )

Tags: c#

I looking for some class that i can use to define number that is 3 base ( ternary number )

Is there something that i can use in .net framework or i need to write something ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you trying to convert numbers between bases?

Comment: Are you talking about integers or fractional numbers? If you're talking about integers: Why do you want to represent the number as base3 internally instead of using normal integers and use base 3 parsing/ToString?

Comment: No, i need to define some table that each of the table values can be one of { 0, 1, 2 } and i need to create all the values that the table can produce ( 7 column in the table )

Comment: How can i use int as base 3 parsing/ToString?

Comment: @Yanshof: you can parse/ToString from/to an Integer for example with this library: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/Convert.aspx

Comment: @Yanshof - Please use the Convert.ToInt32(s,base) function instead of doing something the incorrect way.  There is no reason to define "some" table ( the reason you want to do it that way makes no sense ).

Comment: Unless I'm missing something - this question has absolutely nothing to do with "base 3" representation? I think what he's asking for is an integer which is restricted to the range [0,2] inclusive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You can parse using [`Convert.ToInt32(s,base)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k20k614.aspx) and convert to string using
[`Convert.ToString(i,base)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14kwkz77.aspx)</strike>

Or if your input consists of integers you can use something like this:

```
int CombineBase3(params int[] digits)
{
    int result=0;
    int multiplier;
    Debug.Assert(digits.Length<=20);//Floor(32*log(2)/log(3))
    for(int i=0;i<digits.Length;i++)
    {
      Debug.Assert(digits[i]>=0 && digits[i]<3);
      result+=multiplier*digits;
      multiplier*=3;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or you can be lazy and just use a `byte[]` and save the digits in the array elements and forget all the integer encoding stuff.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know that. What a strange restriction.

Comment: It makes sense, base 10 understandably being the odd one out. I'm surprised they didn't support base 64

Comment: @Matt The Base64 encoding is completely different from encoding integers in base 64. Bases >36 run out of letters, so I understand that they don't support any bigger ones. But implementing an algorithm that supports all bases from 2 to 26 isn't hard. You can special case common bases for higher performance, but I think they should have implemented all bases.

Comment: Sounds like you're far better versed in these things than me, so I will just nod and agree. +1 :)